# How to include a relation to the result of a remote method in loopback?

Tags: node.js, express, loopback

I have a beforeRemote method when updating an attribute. I included a relation in context.args.include but the result returned does not include that relation. Here is an example code

```
Assessment.beforeRemote('prototype.updateAttributes', function(context, data, next){
    context.args.include = ['images'];

    next();
});
```

What am i doing wrong? "images" attribute is not being included to the result returned.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesn't work because "updateAttributes" doesn't use loopback filter to retrieve updated values, it's not a usual "find" request.

I'd use afterRemote instead of beforeRemote and add the code to retrieve datas :

```
Assessment.afterRemote('prototype.updateAttributes', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
    if (!ctx.result) return next();

    if (Array.isArray(modelInstance)) {
        Assessment.find({
            where: {id: {inq: modelInstance.map(instance => instance.id)}},
            include: ['images']
        }).then(data => {
            // ctx.result is sent to client
            ctx.result = [].concat(data);
            next();
        }).catch(err => {
            // pass error to next
            next(err);
        });
    }else{
        Assessment.findOne({
            where: {id: modelInstance.id)},
            include: ['images']
        }).then(data => {
            // ctx.result is sent to client
            ctx.result = Object.assign({}, data);
            next();
        }).catch(err => {
            // pass error to next
            next(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Details here : [loopback 3 remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#ctxresult)